# 0 - Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

Tags: paypal

I'm using the paypal rest API, but I am getting an error. Here is my code:

```
function makePaymentUsingPayPal($total, $currency, $paymentDesc, $returnUrl, $cancelUrl) {

    // set billing address
    $addr = new Address();
    $addr->setLine1('fh52 N Main ST');
    $addr->setCity('Johnstownfhf');
    $addr->setCountry_code('UK');
    $addr->setPostal_code('35345');
    $addr->setState('DF');

    // set credit card information
    $card = new CreditCard();
    $card->setNumber('4111111111111111');
    $card->setType('visa');
    $card->setExpire_month('12');
    $card->setExpire_year('2015');
    $card->setCvv2('123');
    $card->setFirst_name('dgdg');
    $card->setLast_name('dgdgdShopper');
    $card->setBilling_address($addr);

    $fi = new FundingInstrument();
    $fi->setCredit_card($card);

    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

    //$payer = new Payer();
    //$payer->setPayment_method('credit_card');
    //$payer->setFunding_instruments(array($fi));

    // Specify the payment amount.        
    $amountDetails = new Details();
    $amountDetails->setSubtotal('57.41');
    $amountDetails->setTax('0.06');
    $amountDetails->setShipping('0.06');

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('USD');
    $amount->setTotal('5.47');
    $amount->setDetails($amountDetails);

    // ###Transaction
    // A transaction defines the contract of a
    // payment - what is the payment for and who
    // is fulfilling it. Transaction is created with
    // a `Payee` and `Amount` types
    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);
    $transaction->setDescription('sdgdfg This is the payment transaction description.');

    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($returnUrl);
    $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl);

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
    $payment->setIntent("buy");
    $payment->setPayer($payer);
    $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    //print_r($payment);exit; 
    $payment->create($apiContext);

    // return $payment;
}
```

Everything works fine until I call `$payment->create($apiContext);`

Then it shows this error:

> 0 - Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.

Comment: I am having the same issue, has someone figured this out?

Answer (score 18):

If you wrap your call in a try/catch block and catch the PPConnectionException, you can examine the data to see exactly what the error is:

```
// ...
try {
    $response = $pp_payment->create();
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $pce) {
    // Don't spit out errors or use "exit" like this in production code
    echo '<pre>';print_r(json_decode($pce->getData()));exit;
}
```

Comment: This helped although the exception namespace was : `PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException`

Comment: Both the answer and @Iwazaru's comment were very helpful. The exception namespace for the 1.6.2 release of the PayPal PHP SDK is now `PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException`

Answer (score 14):

I think the reason for the 400 is that your subTotal + tax + shipping does not add up to the total.  You should be able to check the reason in the response you get, it should contain an array of errors.

subTotal + tax  + shipping = total

57.41    + 0.06 + 0.06     != 5.47

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. The problem was a `space` that was in the parameters I passed in the **returnurl**.

> Make sure your **$returnUrl** and **$cancelUrl** are [urlencoded](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.urlencode.php)
> if you are passing any special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check if the subtotal and total are correct.
In my case, I was using sandbox, and I didn't pay attention the total and subtotal were not correct. Some cents were making the difference and outputing an error, just fixed the values and it worked properly.